# Menu accelerators for Gnome 3 windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, window, context-menu, window-manager

In most window managers, pressing alt+space brings up the window context menu. Often the context menu items are navigable using `home`/`end`, `pgup`/`pgdn`, and menu accelerators (so, say `alt`+`space`, `c`, or `alt`+`space`, `pgdn` might close the window)

In Gnome 3, you can still open the window menu with `alt`+`space`, but the navigation keys do nothing, and there don't appear to be any menu accelerators.

How do you add back in these menu accelerators?

If not, are there any other window managers that are comparable in features that have menu accelerators?

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733297

Comment: Also take a look at [this great askubuntu answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123223/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-minimise-a-window-to-launcher-in-unity).

Comment: The discussion on the gnome.org bugzilla is amazing: how pervasive/basic does a feature need to be to not be controversial?! Would comment there, but don't remember my username on gnome.org and apparently, there is no way to find out what it was...well done there!

Comment: It's absurd. 4 years later and this is STILL irritating me daily.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested GNOME 3.18 and up/down arrow keys work fine in this version. Though GNOME has always had dedicated shortcut keys for all such operations, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to begin moving the window:

[image]